# codeigniter delete column from database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Have two tables test and languages, I need to delete `title_$lang` column from test table when code column is deleted from language table. The tables are not connected with foreign key. It works with insert function. Here is my script:

model:

```
public function deleteField($table, $id, $code){

             $this->dbforge->drop_column();
            if ($this->db->delete($table, array('id' => $id))&& $this->dbforge->drop_column('tests', "title_".$code)) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', true);
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', true);
        }
        return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : 'backend/tests';
        return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : 'backend/languages';

        }
```

controller:

```
public function removefield($table = 0, $code)
    {
        if (!$table) die('!');
        $id = $this->input->get('id');
        redirect($this->admin_model->deleteField($table, $id, $code));
        echo $code;
    }
```

view:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>backend/removefield/languages/?id=<?php echo $row['id'];?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete</a>
```

It gives the **followint errors:**

> Missing argument 2 for Backend::removefield() Filename:controllers/Backend.php
>
> Undefined variable: code Filename: controllers/Backend.php
>
> Undefined property: Backend::$dbforge Filename: core/Model.php
>
> Call to a member function drop_column() on null Filename: models/Admin_model.php

Comment: what is the issue/error?

Comment: It gives the followint errors: 1) Missing argument 2 for Backend::removefield()

Filename: controllers/Backend.php 2) Undefined variable: code

Filename: controllers/Backend.php 3) Undefined property: Backend::$dbforge

Filename: core/Model.php 4)Call to a member function drop_column() on null

Filename: models/Admin_model.php

Comment: I think you missed load function 

    $this->load->dbforge()

Comment: I tried with that function as well it still doesnt work

Comment: can you display your table structure,so we gave idea ?

Comment: language table: id|code|name(1|en|english) and test table id|test_type|title_en(1|math|en)   each time row in language table is deleted the column (title_en) in test table must be deleted

Comment: I could find the solution, hope it can be helpful for someone: `code` $log = $this->session->userdata('user_log');
        if(isset($log) && $log == 'true'){
            if (!$table) die('Fuck!!!');
            $id = $this->input->get('id');
            $data['data'] = $this->admin_model->getData('languages', $id, 100);
            $this->admin_model->deleteField($data['data']['code']);
           redirect($this->admin_model->removeData($table, $id));
            
      }`code`